# Show $\{x\in E: \|x\|\le 1\}=\bigcap\limits_{f\in E^{\star}\\ \|f\|\le 1}\{x\in E: |f(x)|\le 1\}$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(E,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space and $E^{\star}$ denote the dual space. I want to show that $\{x\in E: \|x\|\le 1\}=\bigcap\limits_{f\in E^{\star}\\ \|f\|\le 1}\{x\in E: |f(x)|\le 1\}$. I can show the inclusion of the first set in the second set but not the second set in the first set. Any hints?

Comment: have you tried using $E^{**}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second inclusion:
$$A:=\bigcap_{f \in E^* , \ ||f|| \leq 1} \{ x \in E : |f(x)| \leq 1\} \subset \{x \in E : ||x|| \leq 1 \}$$
If $x\in A$ then for all $f \in E^*$ with $||f|| \leq 1 $ we have that $|f(x)| \leq 1$. Now, by a Corollary of the Hahn-Banach thm, there exists a functional $ f \in E^*$ with $||f||=1$ and $f(x) = ||x||$. Thus, $||x|| \leq 1$.